# Get a list of inner properties with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongoose schema having the structure of

```
const videoProjectsSchema = new Schema({
   projectname:String,
   projectmeta:String,
   username:String,
   createdat:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

I need to retrieve a list of projectnames which belongs to a particular user. the array returned should only contain the names of the projects or else a **list of projectname**. This is my code(which returns all the projects objects)

```
  videoProjects.find({ username: req.query.username }, function(err, proj) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    res.json(proj);
  });
```

Comment: you need to aggregate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fields` as second parameter to limit fields returned in object.

```
videoProjects.find({ username: req.query.username },{projectmeta:0,username:0,createdat:0,_id:0},
 function(err, proj) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }else 
         res.json(proj);
 });
```

OR

```
videoProjects.find({ username: req.query.username },{projectname:1,_id:0},
     function(err, proj) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }else 
             res.json(proj);
     });
```